# Link to developer's apps on App Store from app

Tags: macos, app-store

How can I get a link to a page with all of our apps in it (even if it opens up in the App Store app)?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html

Comment: @Larme OK, got it. So, it's actually ` http://appstore.com/mac/<companyname>`. And it works! Could you kindly post it as an answer as well, so that I give you all deserved credit? Thanks a lot, mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of Apple Short Links :

- Company Name
- App Name
- App by Company

More info [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html).